# Get a Ruby hash with one element removed (non-destructive)

Tags: ruby

I need to get a new Ruby hash based on an existing hash but with one element removed and without affecting the original hash. I'm sure it's really simple, and I'm too much of a Ruby newbie to spot it.

For example, if I have `plugh={:bar=>"bar", :baz=>"baz"}` I want to be able to do something like  `xyzzy=plugh.some_magic_goes_here(:baz)` and get `xyzzy` set to `{:bar=>"bar"}` without affecting `plugh`in any way. How do I do it?

Comment: store plugh in another hash then delete the key from the second hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *are not* using active support, you can do the following:

```
xyzzy = plugh.reject { |k, _| k == :baz }
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit - for one thing, DreadPirateShawn already suggested something very similar to what you suggest already...

Comment: @UriAgassi Just think what *sh--* internet connection I am using.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails (or at least ActiveSupport), then [except](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) is what you want:

```
xyzzy = plugh.except(:baz)
```

If you're not using Rails, the docs include the source code as well:

```
def except(*keys)
  dup.except!(*keys)
end

def except!(*keys)
  keys.each { |key| delete(key) }
  self
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that too. Answer edited to flesh out the specific code Rails provides for this.

Comment: You won't need all of Rails. Just ActiveSupport.